# How to defined non-null elements inside an array in GraphQL Nexus?

Tags: graphql, nexus

I'm using GraphQL Nexus to implement my GraphQL schema.

The target GraphQL type I want to create is this:

```
input UserCreateInput {
  email: String!
  name: String
  posts: [PostCreateInput!]!
}
```

However, I'm not sure how I can create the `PostCreateInput` array such that the *elements* of the `posts` are are required as well.

Right now this is what I have:

```
input UserCreateInput {
  email: String!
  name: String
  posts: [PostCreateInput]!
}
```

Which is backed by this Nexus type definition:

```
const UserCreateInput = inputObjectType({
  name: 'UserCreateInput',
  definition(t) {
    t.nonNull.string('email')
    t.string('name')
    t.nonNull.list.field('posts', {
      type: 'PostCreateInput',
    })
  },
})
```

Is there a way how I can tell Nexus that each array element should be non-null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, adding a `nonNull` after the `list` should suffice. So something like the following:

```
const UserCreateInput = inputObjectType({
  name: 'UserCreateInput',
  definition(t) {
    t.nonNull.string('email')
    t.string('name')
    t.nonNull.list.nonNull.field('posts', {
      type: 'PostCreateInput',
    })
  },
})
```